# Gmail instant new mail notifier for Debian 7 systems?

Tags: debian, software-installation, email

The way I do it now is that I have to keep a 'Gmail' tab open at all times in my browser to check for new mail. My mails are important and I need instant notifications. I thought of using a client like 'Thunderbird' but it feels to "heavy" for my needs. All I need is instant notifications of a new mail received in my Gmail such that I don't have to keep the browser tab open all the time. Meaning, may be some little script in my Debian system is checking for a new mail after every minute and raises an alarm when there's a new unread email.

If it is able to show me a subject line and 'From' details, that would be a bonus.

I'm open to all kinds of solutions that alert me of a new Google mail such that:

- I do not have to keep a browser tab open.
- It does not download any 
  mail to local disk

Comment: if you're using Chrome give [Checker Plus for gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj?hl=en) a shot. Haven't tried it on Debian but works like a charm on Windows

Comment: I'm using Chromium on Debian, and checker plus tells me I'm using an unstable channel of chrome, so it won't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a browser add-on is one option, if you've got your browser open doing something anyway.

Or a desktop panel app could notify you when new mail arrives. Like "Xfce4 Mailwatch Plugin" (if you're using XFCE, or like it, can do multiple inboxes) or "gnome-gmail-notifier", there should be several available from searching the repositories for "gmail".

Or CheckGmail, gmail-notify, kgmailnotifier, mail-notification, Mailnag... Install some & try them out.

There should even be some one-line shell scripts that could check for new mail using `wget` that might be useful, subject & from are in there, somewhere:

- http://www.shellperson.net/quickly-check-gmail-with-bash/

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ## Quickly checks if I have new gmail

  echo -e "Checking for new messages... \c"

  atomlines=`wget -T 3 -t 1 -q --secure-protocol=TLSv1 \
   --no-check-certificate \
   --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD \
   https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom -O - \
   | wc -l`

  echo -e "\r\c"

  [ $atomlines -gt "8" ] \
   && echo -e " You have new gmail.  \c" \
   || echo -e " No new gmail.  \c"
  ```
- [Using wget to receive an XML atom feed of your Gmail inbox](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6657/using-wget-to-receive-an-xml-atom-feed-of-your-gmail-inbox)

  ```
  wget -O - 'https://USERNAMEHERE:PASSWORDHERE@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom' --no-check-certificate
  ```

Comment: I used to use gmail-notify (or something close to that) sometime ago, but it was just too clumsy. It's hard to explain but it was unreliable. I thought of writing my own shell script like the one you mention in your solution, but security goes down the drain with such scripts. I am not going to put my Gmail username and password in a plaintext format file. Also, I'm using 'two-factor authentication' on my Gmail. So this won't work.

Comment: Ended up using 'Mail notification'. It seems to do the job well for Debian systems. As I was using a two-factor auth, I had to generate an 'app-specific password' for Mail Notification.

Comment: Securing your passphrase can be trouble, some of the programs do just use plaintext in your $HOME :-( Others use something similar to gnome-keyring, maybe even the kernel keyring (with `keyctl`). Or a custom passphrase file in a ram `tmpfs` or eCryptfs / EncFS... *but DIY encryption schemes are often not very secure*